# JS not working on mustacheJS' products?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, mustache

JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hugolpz2/QCjJD/9/

**Given an html** anchors with hard coded buttons, purely JS injected buttons, and Mustache injected buttons, with end result such:

```
<div id="anchor">
    <button class="tpl html status0" data-lexeme="A">A</button>
    <button class="tpl html status0" data-lexeme="B">B</button>
    <button class="tpl PureJS status0" data-lexeme="A"></button><!-- injected with pure JS -->
    <button class="tpl PureJS status0" data-lexeme="B">B</button><!-- injected with pure JS -->
    <button class="tpl Mustache status0" data-lexeme="A">A</button><!-- injected with Mustache -->
    <button class="tpl Mustache status0" data-lexeme="B">B</button><!-- injected with  Mustache -->
</div>
```

**Given the referential data such**

```
var json = [ 
    { "id": "A",   "status": 0  },
    { "id": "B",   "status": 0  },
    { "id": "C",   "status": 1  },
    { "id": "AB",  "status": 1  },
    { "id": "ABC", "status": 1  },
    // { ... } +100 entries
];
```

**Given the JS/JQuery** function classUpdateFromData() which bpdate buttons' class from data.

```
// classUpdateFromData(): 
function classUpdateFromData($set) {
    $($set).each(function (i) {  // <------------------------------ seems this is the trouble! Select html, js,but NOT mustache generated content!
        var lexeme = $(this).data('lexeme');
        var val = getJsonVal(json, lexeme);
        if (val.status === 1) {
            $(this).toggleClass('status1 status0');
        } else { /* nothing yet! */ }
    });
}

classUpdateFromData('#anchor > .tpl');
```

**Why my function only update hard coded buttons and purely JS injected buttons and NOT MustacheJS injected buttons ?**

**How to fix make it works on them all, including Mustache created function ?**

Note: classUpdateFromData() is fired AFTER the templates function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `injectTPL()` function is asynchronous: it actually returns *before* the JSON data is fetched and the templates are rendered.

Look at the call to [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/): it takes a callback function and invokes it when the data becomes ready. That function, in turn, renders the templates and appends the resulting markup to the document.

Since `classUpdateFromData()` is called right after `injectTPL()`, it runs before that callback function is invoked.

You can either invoke `classUpdateFromData()` from the callback passed to `$.getJSON()` or, more generically, refactor `injectTPL()` so it takes a callback itself and invokes it from the callback passed to `$.getJSON()`:

```
function injectTPL(url, list, tplId, anchor, callback) {
    console.log("Mustache TPL = Fired !");
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            var lexeme = list[i]; // "火山口";
            var template = '{{#CFDICT}}{{#'+ lexeme +'}}' + $(tplId).html()
                         + '{{/'+ lexeme +'}}{{/CFDICT}}';
            var info = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
            $(anchor).append(info);
        }
        callback();  // Invoke our own callback.
    });
    console.log("Mustache TPL = End !");
}
```

You can then invoke `classUpdateFromData()` from the callback you pass to `injectTPL()`, and it will be called at the right time:

```
injectTPL(
    'http://d.codio.com/hugolpz/getJson--/App/data/cfdict.json',
    l, '#CFDICT-tpl', '#anchor', function() {
        classUpdateFromData('#anchor > .tpl');
    }
);
```

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QCjJD/10/).